# In App Purchase request results in password prompt

Tags: iphone

With In App purchase on IOS 4 when performing a product request or SKPaymentQueue addTransactionObserver this results in the password prompt being shown. This occurs using a test user account. Why would this happen?

```
 productsRequest= [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:productIdentifiers];
 productsRequest.delegate = self;

[productsRequest start];
```

Comment: For the same reasons a password pops up when you buy an app - spending money requires a little caution?

Comment: No this is when you just add the observer or request product details.